# Is there a way to write a quick function with vue's @click?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I was wondering if it is possible to write something like below;

```
<buttton @click="function(){alert('Yoohooo')}"></button>
```

Without having to write a method in the Vue instance every time I want to use @click for something as small as that.

Comment: Try `@click="alert('Something')"` or `@click="() => alert('Something')"`

Comment: I think it's not possible. It requires reactive instantiated property or method, defined on the vue instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible because Vue trying to add more attributes to DOM and DOM's events in its way with custom attributes and its annotations, methods should be write in `methods` and so on. As you know HTML is displayed by browsers by tag name, Vue also does that by new rules, more syntax but basically it does not allow write javascript function as tag's attributes

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `window-plugin`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/window-plugin

```html
<button @click='$window.alert("You clicked a button.")'>Click Me</button>
<button @click='$window.console.log("A button was clicked.")'>Click Me</button>
<button @click='$window.open("https://www.quickchords.org/", "_blank"))'>Click Me</button>
<h1 :v-text='$document.title' />
```